# Is it possible to have a table with different background colors which automatically update?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, table-styles

I want to have a table inside a Microsoft Word document. The background color of each row should be either white or gray. So lets say even numbered rows should white and odd numbered should be gray. When I insert a new row the following row colors should adapt automatically. Is this possible with Word 2010 and if yes, how can I realise it?

Comment: this question should be rather asked in SuperUser.Com. However, I think **table style feature** is what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy with **Table Styles**:

[image: 1]

Whatever style you select will apply to the entire table, including to rows you add/insert as you go along.

Comment: @Karan he was referring to changing colors based on the contents of the cells, which is something you can do in Excel, but isn't relevant to this question.